# Is there any performance difference parsing text/plain and application/json content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

There are basically 2 queries:

**First:**

My `httpd` server (APIs) has a different origin the my front end. So, I need to handle *OPTIONS* request which makes my final response somewhat (*300-400ms*) slow. To avoid that, I want to use to `text/plain` content, because it doesn't enable *OPTIONS* request. I've already tested this and it works (but not sure about performance).

But I'm just wondering if JSON is faster than text/plain? Here's the data sample I'm sending to server.

```
{"name": "example", "fullName": "example exam", "data": "**THIS IS MOST IMPORTANT. IT IS BASE64 ENCODED IMAGE DATA, SIZE AROUND 100-200 KB**")
```

I want to send same data as `text/plain` to avoid *OPTIONS* request. So is there any performance issue with it? I'm asking this because most people prefer `application/json` (even I prefer it but I need to make my API fast for this special case. Main concern is **image data** that I'm sending.)

**Second:**

I'm using **PHP** Slim Framework for APIs. In their documentation, they have explained you can use custom methods to parse `text/plain` content but I couldn't find any example anywhere. However, following worked for me:

```
$text_content = $request->getBody()->getContents();
```

And then I used `json_decode` method and it worked fine. But is this the right way or it can break in some cases?

Comment: Transport wise content with mimes application/json and text/plain (and others) are the same thing; just text being sent over the wire. The mime just tells the requesting code how it is supposed to handle the content.

Comment: I assume then the time would be same while transferring data to server with any of them. Any idea about 2nd query?